# db:schema:load not setting `NOT NULL` constraint on uuid column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, uuid

I have a `schema.rb` that includes

`t.uuid "uuid", default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false`

and

`add_index "cards", ["uuid"], name: "index_cards_on_uuid", unique: true, using: :btree`

When running

`rake db:schema:load`

The column does NOT get created with the `NOT NULL` attribute, according to the PSQL console and the fact that I can create `Card`s without the `uuid` field.

The `not null` attribute does get set fine if I were to run

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Ruby 2.2.2
Rails 4.2.1
PSQL 9.3.5.0